# javascript/WYSIWYG parentElement returning div instead of p element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am trying to build a WYSIWYG editor with javascript using contentEditable=true. The point which I'm stucked is that on IE document.selection.createRange().parentElement() returns the element that contenteditable is set to true. For an easier comprehension I'll give you an example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   <p>lorem ip|sum dolor</p>
</div>
```

In this example the ' | ' represents the caret. While in chrome when I use the commonAncestorContainer the returning element is p in this example, in IE parentElement returns the container div. In my understanding the browser is ignoring the elements and therefore I cannot figure out on what element is the focus. I won't ask "if there is any way" since I've seen pretty good working WYSIWYG editors, therefore my question is how can I get the "real" parent element in this example? :)

Ah btw, since I'm a new user I can't create tags. I believe "parentElement" would be a good tag for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM `Range`'s `commonAncestorContainer` and `TextRange`'s `parentElement()` are slightly different: `commonAncestorContainer` returns the deepest node (which could be a text node) that contains the whole range while `parentElement()` returns the deepest *element* that contains the whole TextRange. In your example, `commonAncestorContainer` would be the text node "lorem ipsum dolor" while `parentElement()` would return the `<p>` element. If that's what you want, you can get that with Range by checking `commonAncestorContainer`'s nodeType:

```
var containerElement = range.commonAncestorContainer;
if (containerElement.nodeType == 3) {
    containerElement = containerElement.parentNode;
}
```